# How to create an overlapped colored equation?

Tags: equations, color, witharrows

I wonder if there is a tex library that can create an equation like this (found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.06290.pdf) and the authors actually create a figure for this, not in tex)
[image]
With some research, I see that the arrows can be made using [witharrows](https://ctan.org/pkg/witharrows?lang=en) but I am not sure about the colored part, specifically the I_i(D) part where the two colors (dark green & light green) overlap. Any pointer will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You could try with [`annotate-equations`](https://ctan.org/pkg/annotate-equations) or [`tikzmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) package, though I think the figure (`figs/equation.pdf` in the .tar.gz archive [2307.06290](https://arxiv.org/e-print/2307.06290)) in that arXiv paper is actually produced by MS Office Word (the almost Office-specific math font Calibri Math is embedded in the PDF) and then annotated by Quartz PDFcontext (see the PDF producer).

Comment: Hi @muzimuzhiZ thanks for the quick response! I will take a look into these two packages. Seems like they can do exactly this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An attempt using `annotate-equations` package.

```tex
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{annotate-equations}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\mathstrutX{\vphantom{\widetilde{M}}}

\[
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}
  - \eqnmarkbox[orange!50!red]{Q}{Q_{D|M,S} \mathstrutX}
  \propto \log \eqnmarkbox[DodgerBlue]{LMD}{L(\widetilde{M},D_{\text{eval}})}
  \propto \eqnmarkbox[yellow!50!orange]{L0}{L_0 \mathstrutX}
    + F(
      \eqnmarkbox[OliveDrab!40!white]{I1D-InD}{
        \{ \tikzmarknode[outer ysep=0pt]{I1D}{I_1(D)}, I_2(D), \cdots 
          \smash{{\eqnmarkbox[OliveDrab]{IiD}{I_i(D) \mathstrutX}}}, \cdots,
        I_n(D) \}
        \mathstrutX
      }
    )
\]
\tikzset{annotate equations/arrow/.append style={semithick}}
\annotate[yshift=-1em]{below, left}{Q}{Instruction Quality}
\annotate[yshift= 1em]{left}{LMD}{Model Evaluation Loss}
\annotate[yshift=-1em]{below, left}{L0}{Minimal Loss Constant}
\annotate[yshift= 1em]{}{IiD}{$i$th indicator on data $D$}

\tikzset{annotate equations/arrow/.append style={color=OliveDrab}}
\annotate[yshift=-1em, color=OliveDrab]{below}{I1D}{Bag of $n$ indicators}
\end{document}
```

[image]